# bash config syntax error

Tags: bash, perl, vps

I'm setting up a brand new VPS on Bluehost. As soon as I logged in, I knew something was amiss. When I launch a `bash` shell I get this error:

```
bash: eval: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I tracked the problem down to the line `eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)` in  `/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh`:

```
#cPanel Added local::lib -- BEGIN
LOCALLIBUSER=$USER
if [ -e "/usr/bin/whoami" ]; then
    LOCALLIBUSER=`/usr/bin/whoami`
fi
if [ "$LOCALLIBUSER" != "root" ]; then
    eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)
fi
#cPanel Added local::lib -- END
```

When I execute `eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib)` at the bash prompt, I get the error `bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file`. When I execute `perl -Mlocal::lib` at the bash prompt I get this:

```
if ! $?PERL_MB_OPT setenv PERL_MB_OPT '';
setenv PERL_MB_OPT "--install_base "\""/home/MYUSERNAME/perl5"\""";
if ! $?PERL_MM_OPT setenv PERL_MM_OPT '';
setenv PERL_MM_OPT "INSTALL_BASE=/home/MYUSERNAME/perl5";
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I correct it? I'm relatively new to `bash` and utterly hopeless with `perl`, so am on shaky ground here. Thanks!

Comment: What output do you get when you run: `perl -Mlocal::lib`?  I'd expect nothing, or possibly Perl hangs waiting for you to type something — in which case `exit;` should get you your prompt back.  (Me, I get `Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: …)`, etc.)  IOW, I think that cPanel fragment in the shell file is dubious — especially the Perl part.

Comment: you can run directly rub the perl command.

`perl -Mlocal::lib`

Comment: I added the `perl` output to my question. I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: Commands shown by `$(perl -Mlocal::lib)` are not correct bash commands. Both `if`s are missing `then` and `fi` sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside `local::lib` is misidentifying your shell as `csh` for some reason.  You can force it with `--shelltype bourne` according to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/local-lib-2.000018/lib/local/lib.pm).

```
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=--shelltype,bourne)
```

I'm speculating that your account may have been set up with `tcsh` as your default shell.  You can change this permanently with `chsh`, in which case this workaround should hopefully not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. The error message went away when I changed the line to `eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=--shelltype,bourne)`.